# How to save Entries in tkinter local in certain storage location with certain name on computer (Python 3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, local-storage

I created a desktop application using tkinter and Python 3. The user is asked to enter in their name, mail and number (I save those entries as variables). The user can then either click on the button "Save", "Read in" or "Quit".

In case the user clicks on "Save", I want to enable the user to decide in which storage location to save those entries. Moreover, they should be able to type in the name of the data.
Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how to implement that stuff.

I am thankful for all help and information!!!

Best wishes
Lea

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. What part of the problem are you struggling with? Do you know how to create entries? Buttons? Do you know how to open a file dialog? Do you know how to open and write to a file? Your question needs to focus on a very specific part of the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

`tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile` will do this.  It will present a dialog, let the user pick a file name, and then return to you an open file object that you can write to.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html